# Cumulative sum with addition or subtraction depending on the condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In the `df` dataframe in the example, I want to perform **cumulative sum** based on the **transaction type**, on a per-customer basis.

If the transaction type is **buy**, the `count` column will be sum; If it is a **sell**, the difference will be taken by multiplying the previous value by the value in the `percentage` column.

In summary, while the count will be sum in the buy transaction, the percentage value of the accumulated count in the sell transaction will be sold as in the `percentage` column.

Thus, the `final_df` dataframe will be reached.

- Here is the example dataframe:

```py
date = ['2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-04',
        '2022-01-08', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10']
customer = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
trading = ['buy', 'buy', 'buy', 'sell', 'sell', 'sell', 'buy', 'sell']
count = [1200, 1200, 2100, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0]
percentage = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 0.5]
process = ['1200',
           '1200 + 1200 = 2400',
           '2400 + 2100 = 4500',
           '4500 - 4500*0.1 = 4050',
           '4050 - 4050*0.2 = 3240',
           '3240 - 3240*0.1 = 2916',
           '2916 + 70 = 2986',
           '2986 - 2986*0.5 = 1493']
value = [1200, 2400, 4500, 4050, 3240, 2916, 2986, 1493]

data = {'date':date,'customer':customer,'trading':trading,
        'count':count,'percentage':percentage,
        'process':process,'value':value}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
| date       | customer | trading | count | percentage | process                | value|
|------------|----------|---------|-------|------------|------------------------|------|
| 2022-01-04 | 1        | buy     | 1200  | 0.0        | 1200                   | 1200 |
| 2022-01-04 | 1        | buy     | 1200  | 0.0        | 1200 + 1200 = 2400     | 2400 |
| 2022-01-04 | 1        | buy     | 2100  | 0.0        | 2400 + 2100 = 4500     | 4500 |
| 2022-01-04 | 1        | sell    | 0     | 0.1        | 4500 - 4500*0.1 = 4050 | 4050 |
| 2022-01-08 | 1        | sell    | 0     | 0.2        | 4050 - 4050*0.2 = 3240 | 3240 |
| 2022-01-09 | 1        | sell    | 0     | 0.1        | 3240 - 3240*0.1 = 2916 | 2916 |
| 2022-01-09 | 1        | buy     | 70    | 0.0        | 2916 + 70 = 2986       | 2986 |
| 2022-01-10 | 1        | sell    | 0     | 0.5        | 2986 - 2986*0.5 = 1493 | 1493 |
```

```py
final_df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[-1:][['date','customer','value']])
final_df
```

```
| date       | customer | value |
|------------|----------|-------|
| 2022-01-10 | 1        | 1493  |
```

- Here are the methods I've tried:

```py
# Created next and previous transaction
df['t_prev'] = df.trading.shift(1)
df['t_next'] = df.trading.shift(-1)
```

```py
# combining current-previous-next transaction options
# 2^3 combination(bbb,bbs,bsb....sss)
choi = [
    #1
    ((df.trading=='buy')&(df.tradingp=='buy')&(df.tradingn=='buy')),
    
    #2
    (((df.trading=='buy')&(df.tradingp=='buy')&(df.tradingn=='sell'))),
    
    #3
    (((df.trading=='buy')&(df.tradingp=='sell')&(df.tradingn=='buy'))),
    
    #4
    (((df.trading=='buy')&(df.tradingp=='sell')&(df.tradingn=='sell'))),
    
    #5
    ((df.trading=='sell')&(df.tradingp=='buy')&(df.tradingn=='buy')),
    
    #6
    (((df.trading=='sell')&(df.tradingp=='buy')&(df.tradingn=='sell'))),
    
    #7
    (((df.trading=='sell')&(df.tradingp=='sell')&(df.tradingn=='buy'))),
    
    #8
    (((df.trading=='sell')&(df.tradingp=='sell')&(df.tradingn=='sell')))
        ]
```

```py
cond = [
    #1
    df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum(),
    
    #2
    df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum(),
    
    #3
    df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum(),
    
    #4
    df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum(),
    
    #5
    (
         df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)\
         - (df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)*df['percentage'])
    ),
    
    #6
    (
         df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)\
         - (df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)*df['percentage'])
    ),
    
    #7
    (
         (
             df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)\
             - (df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)*df['percentage'])
         )\    

        -(
             df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)\
             - (df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)*df['percentage'])
         )*df['percentage']
    ),
    
    #8
    (
        (
            df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)\
            - (df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)*df['percentage'])
        )\
        
        -(
            df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)\
            - (df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum().shift(1)*df['percentage'])
        )*df['percentage']
    )
        ]
```

```py
df['value'] = np.select(choi,cond,df.groupby(['customer'])['count'].cumsum())
final_df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[-1:][['date','customer','value']])
```

I would be glad if you can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved but it's not a feasible solution for me. I have lots of customer and trading rows. So I need pandas or numpy solution for speed.

Here is my code:

```py
di = {'buy':23, 'sell':24}
df = df.replace({'trading': di})

df['t_prev'] = df.trading.shift(1).fillna(0)

top = 0
for c in df.values:
    
    if ((c[2] == 23)&(c[7] <= 23)):#c[2] trading, c[7] t_prev columns
        top = top + c[3]#count column
    elif ((c[2] == 23)&(c[7] > 23)):
        top = top + c[3]#count column
    else:
        top = top - top*c[4]#percentage column
    print(top)
```